# Why the current in this graph is so strange?

Tags: current, graph

I have a question about a 3-phase 400V motor used by an hydraulic pump.

I read its currents and their graph is quite strange to me, far from the usual (deformed) wave.

What could be going on here? [image]

Comment: Looks like some significant harmonic content. Some kind of mechanical resonance maybe?

Comment: This graph is very satisfying to look at for some odd reason.

Comment: Not at that time based/frequency.

Comment: What's your sampling rate? Are you performing any average in your plotting (kind of default in Excel)?

Comment: what type of pump? (i'm guessing a gear pump) ... how did you obtain the measurement?

Comment: @winny and jsotola: it is possibly a gear pump (but I am not sure), sampling rate is 32kHZ, obtained with a Yokogawa Power Analyzer. I was graphing the values and was surprised to see such a big distortion.

Comment: Graphing yes, but are you averaging by any chance? It looks just like a folding phenomonon. That, or some strange drive with peak rectification.

Comment: No, I am not averaging. I need to check if there is some hidden param in the Yokogawa but after a first check there wasn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A motor like transformers has some excitation current  that causes some <10% phase lead on current with respect to voltage (not given/shown.)

But what is shown is the current of each phase with a dominant 3rd harmonic current from the non-linear core ( partial saturation at peak voltage).

By hand drawing a similar sine wave with a 3rd harmonic and adjusting the phase and amplitude, I see that the 3rd harmonic is approximately 41% of the fundamental and the phase is 1.95 radians phase lead.  Since reactance increases 300% with 3rd harmonic, we expect this for an inductor. But the core having partial saturation properties shows that the 3rd harmonic content is between 1/3 and 1/2 of the fundamental.  THis is stored energy and not contributing to work by the motor. (VAR)

The pump load will also emphasize the current harmonics and sub-harmonics if a gear ratio is involved.(not observed or analyzed) as the load is not linear throughout the pump cycle.

[image]
The fundamental above is normalized to 1 @ 0 deg phase near 50Hz with the 3rd harmonic only shown in yellow with composite waveform in red.
You can see the website where to analyze FFT and settings that I used.
[image]